# How to merge two Facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am the admin of two Facebook pages. I heard of merging the pages and combining them into one. I followed the directions to *Edit Page* → *Edit settings* → *Merge Pages* → *Merge duplicate Pages*, but I couldn’t find the merge option. Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be the *owner* of both pages and the page names must match or be similar for the duplicate page to appear in the merge options.